# jquery slowly append span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making an online portfolio and have a skills section.  In this skills section, I would like to slowly append some slashes to portray the skill level.  I've tried several variations on a jquery function, but I can't get anything to come up correctly.  I would like to write a function that accepts the level of skill as a parameter and be applicable to different classes.

Here is the code for the first skill:

```
<div class="skillDiv">{<span id="hskill" class="mOrange"></span>}<br /></div>
```

What I would like to do is slowly add slashes to the span part, but I would like to be able to use the same function on other spans of different classes.  Something like:

```
function slasher(level){
    var element = $(this).attr(id)
    for (i=0; i<level; i++){
        element.append('/').show('slow')
    }
}
```

I had a specific id on the span, but that didn't seem to help with the jquery function.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I edited OP to show the id.  I had it out while testing a different loop and forgot to put it back in before posting.  It is now the first attribute of the span tag.

Comment: code is too fragmented...scope of `this` will be determined by how you use the function, which isn't shown, and likely needs to be passed in as argument

Comment: `for` loop doesn't make sense either, can only show something once without hiding it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want something like this
http://static.alanedwardes.com/jquery-cascade.html

Comment: That looks like exactly what I want happening.  I'm going to try applying it to the span in question.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm having trouble applying it to my situation.  Any advice on how to apply it in different degrees to different spans?  Looks like this will append ten slashes each time.